# EmEditorで複数行にまたがる条件の正規表現についての機能はありますでしょうか？

Tags: 正規表現, emeditor

お世話になっております。
正規表現は前後の行にまたがった条件は一般的には難しいとされていると思います。
ほとんどの解説サイトは1行単位での組み合わせのマッチングです。

たとえば以下のような場合です。

例
前の行に"スイス"という単語がある場合の次の行に"登山"という言葉がある場合のみ二行のマッチングでヒットする。

このような検索です。

例
前後の5行以内(合計11行)に"スイス"という単語がある場合の前後5行以内に"登山"という言葉がある場合のみマッチングでヒットする。

このような検索です。

これは普通の正規表現でも、もしかしたらできるのかもしれませんが、できたとしても初心者には記述の難易度が高いです。
ほとんどの正規表現サイトはそこまでの複雑な行程まで説明していないです。

普通の正規表現では「4回空行の改行が連続して続けてある」という検索だけでも難しいです。

EmEditorに、これを簡単にする機能はありますでしょうか？

EmEditorではフィルター機能で前後の行が表示できる機能がありましたので、それに使い機能です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: これまでのすべての質問についてもそうですが，質問が解決した場合はその回答を「承認」してください．ヘルプの[「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ 」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) も読んでください．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- スイスと登山が同一行以内にある場合
  `スイス.*?登山`
- スイスと登山が2行以内にある場合
  `スイス([^\n]*\n)?.*?登山`
- スイスと登山が5行以内にある場合
  `スイス([^\n]*\n){0,4}.*?登山`
- 4回空行が連続
  `^\n\n\n\n`

Comment: ありがとうございます。検索出来ました。いつも回答していただきありがとうございます。御厚意､感謝しております。

Answer (score 1):

改行コードを追加することでマッチング可能かと思います。

例：

```
スイス\r\n登山
```

**追記**
検索オプションに検索行数の指定ができるようです。

[複数行にマッチする正規表現は書けますか？ - EmEditor フォーラム](https://jp.emeditor.com/forums/topic/%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%AB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%AF%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%91%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%EF%BC%9F/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。